# URL filtering in php, filter_var or htmlentities

Tags: php, security

For a secure url query, what is more secure? [filter_var($string, FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS)](http://tr.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) or [htmlentities](http://tr.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) ?

Comment: For a URL, wouldn't `urlencode()` or `FILTER_SANITIZE_URL` be better options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you defending against?  A vulnerability is highly dependent on how the data is being used.  Its impossible to create 1 function call that protects against everything,  and mixing protection systems (like xss and sql injection) is a very bad idea.

For XSS you should use: `htmlspecialchars($var, ENT_QUOTES);`

For Sql Injection in mysql you should use `mysql_real_escape_string($var);`

If you are passing user input to `system()` or another similar function then you should use `escapeshellarg($var);`

These are the top 3 and mixing these will cause nothing but problems.

Comment: Defending against both XSS and injection. Do this mean that "I have to" mix theme anyway?

Comment: @phpExe No,  not really.  XSS is only an issue when you are printing data,  and sql injection is only an issue when you are building queries.   If you **really**  want data to be htmlspecialchar'ed in the database (i advise against this because it can screw up comparisons) then do a `mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($var, ENT_QUOTES));`.  In the case of sql injection make sure the escape routine is always the very last operation before building the query.

Comment: Thanks The Rook, You are my idol.

Answer (score 3):

The first one is clearly designed for such a purpose.